# How to get gps location for every half an hour android?

Tags: android, gps, location

i have to switch on gps once for every half an hour and get location and switch it off is there any code for this function as i am new to android kindly help me pls.

thank you.

here is my code:

```
public void checkLocation(View v) {
        //initialize location manager
        manager =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //check if GPS is enabled
        //if not, notify user with a toast
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is disabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //get a location provider from location manager
            //empty criteria searches through all providers and returns the best one
            String providerName = manager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
            if (location != null) {
                tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Last known location not found. Waiting for updated location...");
            }
            //sign up to be notified of location updates every 15 seconds - for production code this should be at least a minute
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 60000*3, 1, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you can use pending Intent to achive this

Comment: Hi @vinoth thanks for your head up can you help me with this??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785915/how-to-check-the-gps-tracking-half-hour-once-using-broadcast-receiver duplicate

Comment: There are plenty of samples in the net link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627035/updating-notification-in-android-every-half-n-hour

Answer (score 0):

I would make it with a runnable function. This is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android) for it

You shoud set the `handler.postDelayed(r, 5400000);` (if i calculate right).
The value are miliseconds.

Comment: I am asking this just to know will this execute for every half an hour repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

i have not code this time,but i will suggest u to use system alarm and kept a time  interval 
of half an hour.android alarm r usually used where we have to do some work after every interval so that battery will also remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,+long,+float,+android.app.PendingIntent%29) method that takes a [PendindIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) that you can respond to.

Answer (score -1):

```
thread1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000*60*30);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {


                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Write your code here to get the gps location.
                   });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Jai Kumar can you say me how to implement this in my code

Comment: Use the Gpstracker.java[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/] class in this link..

Comment: What is mHandler?